# How can i expose a web service in Grails made with Java?

Tags: web-services, grails, soap

I need to expose a web service in my Grails application but made in Java, the reason to this is that any of the Grails plugins for web services, does what we need, but after looking at Spring services, I know is possible, after all Grails is made upon Spring

Note that I'm speaking of a Service as a Web Service, not a Servlet, a SOAP to be exact. If I don't find a way to do this in Java, my superiors are pointing to .NET and I really going to hate doing that going to .NET from Java is just wrong.

=== Software currently used ===
-> Grails Version 2.4.3
-> WebService type must be SOAP I have no other choice since my superior does not like REST
-> Spring 4
-> IDE is Intellij

Comment: https://grails.org/plugin/cxf you done a search with soap grails on google ? have a look at that plugin it might help

Comment: Sorry to disapoint, but that was the first one i tried and apart that is very broken, it has no control over the message, i need a way to use apache cxf without the plugin

Comment: You want to create soap webservice in java right. I think this link should help you http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/